# Setting app_idle_timeout for shiny changes nothing

Tags: r, ubuntu, shiny, shiny-server, ubuntu-22.04

I want my shiny app to remain active continuously so that anyone who accesses the link can instantly use the app without waiting for it to start. According to [documentation](https://docs.posit.co/shiny-server/#application-timeouts) app_idle_timeout set to large values should solve my problem but it doesn't.

My app is running on Ubuntu 22.04. I tried to change default.config file which is in "/opt/shiny-server/config/" directory as it is advised [here](https://groups.google.com/g/shiny-discuss/c/tUcEMk1Av8Y).

Comment: From your documentation, `Setting app_idle_timeout to 0 will disable the app idle time out.`, wouldn't this accomplish what you want?

Comment: @Chris, thank you for suggestion but it doesn't work as well :(

Comment: Have you `pinged` around with something like `nmap` to try and assess whether it is a network or server delay?

Comment: @Chris I didn't but the issue with long loading arises when there is no active user of an app for 5 sec so it seems that it is all about the parameter app_idle_timeout (the default for it is 5 sec). My guess is that I should make some further steps so that shiny-server would take new configuration into account. But I haven't find info on this

Comment: How long is 'long loading', go make a cup of coffee and call your mother long, or three seconds long? have a look at 2.6 Local App Configurations. I'm just reading through the documentation now to get a sense of things and someone who really knows `shiny` will come along.

Comment: I think I found the solution! Thank you, @Chris! Your answers pushed my mind in the right direction. I will click "Answer Your Question" and leave a solution for future generations :)

Comment: I'll be an interested reader myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another config file called shiny-server.config in "/etc/shiny-server/" directory which should be altered instead of default.config in "/opt/shiny-server/config/"

It also seems that shiny-server restart is [required](https://docs.posit.co/shiny-server/) for changes to come, so paste the following code in your Linux command line

```
systemctl restart shiny-server
```